# Identifying Primary Key field of Layer in ArcGIS Server using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, enterprise-geodatabase

I need to get the primary key column of the Particular layer added in the Map.
Usually 'FID' be found for a Shapefile Layer Source and OBJECTID  found for a SDE source layer.

Is there any way to Identify which one is the primary key columns so that I can access those values.

I need to get this using ArcGIS JS API Version.3.3 and I am using ArcGIS Server 10.

Comment: You can use "ObejectID".. I am using ObjectID column to display the attribute information of feature. For details please check ArcGIS Java Script API 3.3 samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle this using [esri.request](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.request-amd.html), or directly perform an [AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Either way, you want to hit the layer's ArcGIS Server REST API.

Eg take the sample layer http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/2

You can interrogate this via an AJAX request to http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/2?f=json and examine the `fields` response, which contains:

`{"name":"objectid","type":"esriFieldTypeOID","alias":"OBJECTID","domain":null}`

Note the type indicates it's the OID field.

Answer (score 0):

You could check it with Python...

```
import arcpy

layer= r"Put here the path to your data"
dscfc = arcpy.Describe(layer)

if dscfc.hasOID == True:
    print dscfc.OIDFieldName
else:
    print "No Primary Key found."
```

The OIDFieldName is the PK for the table.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the fields for each layer and find the Object ID data type.

Comment: Is there any example, or link to documentation you could provide?